# Kinetic js scroll with mouse wheel event

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

I am using [kinetic js](http://davetayls.me/jquery.kinetic/) to implement scroll on a div,It working fine,But i need to scroll with my mouse wheel event also.

```
<div id="wrapper"  style="cursor: move;">
 <div id="inner">
  <img src="http://davetayls.me/jquery.kinetic/wembley.jpg" alt="wembley stadium">
 </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
  $('#wrapper').kinetic();
```

I dont know how to do,Please help me.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tN8Z/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Brandon Aaron's mousewheel plugin for jQuery.  It works well!

https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

Example code (be sure you download jquery.mousewheel.js and adjust the script tag accordingly)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="includes/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);


    var circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x:100,
        y:100,
        radius: 30,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(circle1);
    layer.draw();


    $('#container').bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      var deltaY=event.deltaY;
      circle1.y(circle1.y()-deltaY*10);
      layer.draw();
    });


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <h4>Click in the gray rect to get focus then<br>Scroll the mousewheel to move the circle.</h4>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```